# Restoring an SQL database on a Remote Server

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, database-restore

I have remote access to a server, and I want to copy an sql database from my computer to the server.

Both my computer, and the server use Microsoft SQL 2008 R2.

I created a backup of the database on my computer, then copy/Paste it on the remote server. But then when I tried to restore it on the server I get this error:

> The media family on device 'c:\Web_Database.bak' is incorrectly
>   formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Can you verify the backup on the source installation? Do the two installations have the same service pack installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to "Generate Scripts"

Right click on the database you want to copy / restore.
Tasks
Generate Scripts
Next
Next ( Do not check the checkbox )
Scroll down to Table/View Options and set "Script Data" to "true" then click Next
Check "Tables" - click Next
Click "select all" - Click Next 
Set your path to generate the script to
Finish

Copy the script onto your server
Open SQL 2008 R2
Delete your previous attempt at restoring the database - we need a fresh one.
Create your new database 
Go to the location where you copied your script to and double click on the script - this will automatically open SQL.
Top line of code where it says "USE [databasename]" - delete this line. 
Next to execute select the drop down and choose the data base you are trying to restore.
Click Execute.

Let the query run and then you are done :-)

Comment: thank you for your help. this worked but it only transfered the column titles. I need the data to be transfered too. it created an empty database with the same structure as the original but without the content. How can I also get the contents? thanks

Comment: I think you've missed a step. Choose Script Options / Generate Data <- set this to True